# How to implement LSTM layer with multiple cells per memory block in Pytorch?

Tags: lstm, pytorch

I intend to implement an LSTM in Pytorch with multiple memory cell blocks - or multiple LSTM units, an LSTM unit being the set of a memory block and its gates - per layer, but it seems that the base class `torch.nn.LSTM` enables only to implement a multi-layer LSTM with one LSTM unit per layer:

```
lstm = torch.nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers)
```

where (from the Pytorch's documentation):

- `input_size` is the input dimension of the network,
- `hidden_size` is the hidden state dimension for every layer (i.e. the dimension of every layer),
- `num_layer` is the number of layers of the network

Thereupon, from above, each LSTM unit has exactly one cell (the cell state for each LSTM unit is thus a scalar) because for each layer the dimension of the cell state corresponds to the dimension of the hidden state (i.e. `hidden_size`).

However in the original LSTM model proposed by Hochreiter and Schmidhuber
[1997], each LSTM block/unit can contains several cells:
[LSTM Network [Hochreiter, 1997]](https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-3714ad776948339181a2484495a6e428)

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

For my understanding, the two LSTM-Cells are connected as usual. The description of Figure 2 in this paper, says following:

> ...(note that by rotating Figure 1 by 90 degrees anticlockwise, it will match with corresponding parts of Figure 2)...

The graph in Figure 2 is probably hard to interpret, but it should be a LSTM with the input of hidden_layer and the state.